# Как при авторизации на NGINX следующий за ним сервер должен понять, какой пользователь отправил запрос?

Tags: nginx, веб-сервер

В рамках учебного проекта хотелось бы реализовать проксирование пользовательских запросов через NGINX с ngx_http_auth_basic_module, но есть вопрос: как сервер, на который проксируется запрос, узнает, какой юзер (логин при авторизации) отправил запрос?

Comment: У nginx есть переменная `$remote_user`, запроксируйте её через `proxy_set_header` например

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо, помогло!